# redirect https to http for specific url

Tags: php, html, http, https

i want to redirect HTTPS to HTTP for spesific url like :

http://www.example.com/abc.php

this script working well redirected to HTTPS for all pages, but i don't know how to redirect HTTP for specific url

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on" && $settings['ssl_host'] == "yes") {
    $porthttps = "https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    header("Location: " . $porthttps);
    exit();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want a single page to be less secure than others?

Comment: Did you try the combination of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and `stripos` function?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton legacy software that uses this endpoint and only supports HTTP?